# Azure IoT Hub Java SDKs have X.509 certificate support?

Tags: java, sdk, x509, azure-iot-hub

Could someone let me know whether the Azure IoT Java Service SDK has capability to register a device which authenticates using X.509 certificates?
Also, can the Azure IoT Java Device SDK send MQTT by authenticating using X.509 certificates?

Many thanks.

Pls Refer;

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#supported-x509-certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jayaweera 
This is work in progress and we expect to have CA signed certs support in both the device and the service clients by the end of the month.
You can track progress in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Is this functionality complete in the Azure IoT Java Service/Device SDKs?

Comment: The feature is complete for MQTT and AMQP. You can check this on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java#key-features-and-roadmap